# vb.customize 'storageattach' mounts my disk first time, but changes are lost after vagrant halt ; vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

i am new to vagrant and am trying to add a second disk to the virtual machine i am cooking up with vagrant.
 i figured out how to attach the disk when the VM is first booted, but when i bring the machine down
 and then back up again (with 'vagrant up --provision' to make sure the provisioners run) the changes i make to the disk
 are lost.

I ran both times with logging and the log output for the second run  (the reboot after the machine is initially provisioned)  shows that the  storageattach command being executed.  But every file i create under "/dev/shm"   (which seems to be the mount point for the second disk)  disappears.

The failure mode is:

vagrant up ...

```
 touch /dev/shm/some.file
 ls /dev/shm/some.file   # see output here...
```

vagrant halt

vagrant up --provision

```
ls /dev/shm/some.file     #  no such file or directory.. where did it go ?
```

any tips would be  most appreciated.

My Vagrantfile is:

...

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.4.3"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
disk = './secondDisk.vdi'
BOX_NAME="test"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.define :master do |master|
        master.vm.box = "centos65"
        master.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/download/v6.5.1/centos65-x86_64-20131205.box"
        master.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
          v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4196"]
          v.name = BOX_NAME
        end
        master.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
        master.vm.hostname = BOX_NAME
    end

    config.vm.synced_folder(".", "/vagrant",
        :owner => "vagrant",
        :group => "vagrant",
        :mount_options => ['dmode=777','fmode=777']
    )
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        unless File.exist?(disk)
            vb.customize ['createhd', '--filename', disk, '--variant', 'Fixed', '--size', 1 * 1024]
        end
        vb.customize ['storageattach', :id,  '--storagectl', 'SATA', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', disk]
    end
end
```

and here is the log output of the second 'vagrant up --provision'   [ i am using --provision to ensure all provisioning steps are done with each vagrant up ]:

```
INFO sanedefaults: Automatically figuring out whether to enable/disable NAT DNS proxy...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "modifyvm", "ea5c09                              e7-11e7-4630-a7ca-ec66461b9eb6", "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::Customize:0x3dc9818>
 INFO interface: info: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
 INFO interface: info: ==> master: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> master: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "storageattach", "e                              a5c09e7-11e7-4630-a7ca-ec66461b9eb6", "--storagectl", "SATA", "--port", "1", "--device", "0", "--type", "hdd", "-                              -medium", "./secondDisk.vdi"]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
```

Comment: Did you follow the setting from this url: https://gist.github.com/leifg/4713995, any difference?

Comment: I have some suggestions from my colleague Peter Wells which I will post for now. I am going to try to create a little 'mount' script to integrate with my Vagrant recipe, and I will post the full result if i get it working.  >> . (from Peter): You’re looking for the extra hard disk under /dev/shm, but according to the output of the mount command:
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")

So, it seems that /dev/shm is actually a temporary file system 
The second hard disk is attached, but it has no partitions and is not mounted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to BMW for the well engineered and stylish answer, and Peter as well. The referenced article (gist.github.com/leifg/4713995) had the magic, which i will reproduce below in a Vagrant script and a corresponding bootstrap file that makes a file system from the newly added second disk, and adds it to /etc/fstab.  This completely solves my problem   [ no more disappearing data ].

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.4.3"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

disk = './secondDisk.vdi' 
BOX_NAME="test"


Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.define :master do |master|
        master.vm.box = "centos65"
        master.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/download/v6.5.1/centos65-x86_64-20131205.box"
        master.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
          v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4196"]
          v.name = BOX_NAME
        end
        master.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
        master.vm.hostname = BOX_NAME
    end

    config.vm.synced_folder(".", "/vagrant",
        :owner => "vagrant",
        :group => "vagrant",
        :mount_options => ['dmode=777','fmode=777']
    )

    # create the second disk and attach it
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        unless File.exist?(disk)
            vb.customize ['createhd', '--filename', disk, '--variant', 'Fixed', '--size', 1 * 1024]
        end

        vb.customize ['storageattach', :id,  '--storagectl', 'SATA', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', disk]
    end

    # NEW - invoke script which  partitions the new disk (/dev/sdb) 
    # and create mount directives in /etc/fstab
    #config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"  
    config.vm.provision "shell" do |shell|
        shell.inline = "sudo /vagrant/bootstrap.sh"  
    end
end
```

bootstap script:

```
#!/bin/bash  -x

#   configure and mount second disk 
#
yum install -y parted
parted /dev/sdb mklabel msdos
parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary 512 100%
mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1
mkdir /mnt/disk
echo `blkid /dev/sdb1 | awk '{print$2}' | sed -e 's/"//g'` /mnt/disk   xfs   noatime,nobarrier   0   0 >> /etc/fstab
mount /mnt/disk
```

Comment: Nice answer. There is just a problem : `parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary 512 100%`  . "512" is in Mo, so the partition starts at 512Mo.

Comment: Thank you. it's been a while since i've been doing this stuff, but if I go back to it, i will keep your comment in mind ;^)